# List of blobs in Azure Storage from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

We're currently using Azure storage to back up our SQL Server databases, and I've been tasked with recreating a list of the blobs in the database. Currently we use BACKUP TO URL with the credentials stored in `sys.credentials`.

Is it possible to get a list of containers in a storage account and/or get a list of blobs in a container straight from SQL Server with the saved credentials from the database?

Comment: You actually want to make Azure Storage API calls from SQL Server to Azure Storage??? You'd need CLR procedures to accomplish that, as you'd need to make REST calls (but this is a major "code smell").

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to get a list of containers in a storage account and/or get a list of blobs in a container straight from SQL Server with the saved credentials from the database?

As David Makogon said, if you’d like to list containers/blobs from SQL Server, you could try to use SQL CLR stored procedure. And I have a working sample to list blobs from a container, you could refer to it.

SQL CLR StoredProcedure

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void SqlStoredProcedure1 ()
{

    // Put your code here

    string StorageAccount = "myaccount";
    string StorageKey = "accountkey";

    string containername = "mycontainer";

    string requestMethod = "GET";
    string mxdate = "";
    string storageServiceVersion = "2014-02-14";

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&comp=list",
            StorageAccount,
            containername
            ));

    req.Method = requestMethod;

    //specify request header

    mxdate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");

    string canonicalizedHeaders = string.Format(
            "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
            mxdate,
            storageServiceVersion);

    string canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}\ncomp:list\nrestype:container", StorageAccount, containername);

    string stringToSign = string.Format(
        "{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}",
        requestMethod,
        canonicalizedHeaders,
        canonicalizedResource);

    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey));

    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

    String authorization = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}",
        "SharedKey",
        StorageAccount,
        signature
        );
    string AuthorizationHeader = authorization;

    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader);
    req.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", mxdate);
    req.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        StringReader theReader = new StringReader(content);
        DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
        theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

        dt = theDataSet.Tables[2];
    }

    string blobs = "";

    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        blobs += item[0].ToString() + ";";
    }

    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(blobs);
}
}
```

The common language runtime (CLR) integration feature is off by default in Microsoft SQL Server and must be enabled in order to use SQL Server project items. To [enable CLR integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.90).aspx), use the clr enabled option of the sp_configure stored procedure.

And you could refer to [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/calling-web-service-from-sql-server-using-sql-clr) to know how to use SQL CLR stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you. That might be what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Fred Han -MSFT As per your Answer, We can get the list of all files in a any Blob Container.But here SAS token will not be a permanent one.So how could we solve this SAS ?

Comment: @Jayendran, You could have your SAS token be based on an Access Policy, and set the expiration time for that policy to be in thousands of years to achieve the same result as a non-expiring credential. (Access Policy so that you can revoke the token later by changing/deleting the policy and don't have a non-expiring token out in the wild that you can't terminate).