# List of blobs in Azure Storage from SQL Server CLR Proc, not getting full list

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm getting the top 30 or so instead of the full list containing 100+, why is that?

I obtained this code from here [List of blobs in Azure Storage from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262977/list-of-blobs-in-azure-storage-from-sql-server). I does a good job of getting part of what I need, but not a list of everything inside that container, all of which are the same file type.

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void SqlStoredProcedure1 ()
{

    // Put your code here

    string StorageAccount = "myaccount";
    string StorageKey = "accountkey";

    string containername = "mycontainer";

    string requestMethod = "GET";
    string mxdate = "";
    string storageServiceVersion = "2014-02-14";

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}?restype=container&comp=list",
            StorageAccount,
            containername
            ));

    req.Method = requestMethod;

    //specify request header

    mxdate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");

    string canonicalizedHeaders = string.Format(
            "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
            mxdate,
            storageServiceVersion);

    string canonicalizedResource = string.Format("/{0}/{1}\ncomp:list\nrestype:container", StorageAccount, containername);

    string stringToSign = string.Format(
        "{0}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{1}\n{2}",
        requestMethod,
        canonicalizedHeaders,
        canonicalizedResource);

    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(StorageKey));

    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

    String authorization = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}",
        "SharedKey",
        StorageAccount,
        signature
        );
    string AuthorizationHeader = authorization;

    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader);
    req.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", mxdate);
    req.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        StringReader theReader = new StringReader(content);
        DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
        theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

        dt = theDataSet.Tables[2];
    }

    string blobs = "";

    foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
    {
        blobs += item[0].ToString() + ";";
    }

    SqlContext.Pipe.Send(blobs);
}
}
```

Comment: Azure is the Front End Processor and the SQL Server is the Back End Database.  Yo uhave to read the Azure documentation to find out why data is coming in chunks.  Check the HTTP status to make sure you are getting a 200 OK.  You may be getting data in chunks and getting a 100 Continue.  HTTP has a stream mode http1.0 where all data would be received in one chunk and HTTP 1.1 chunk mode where data is coming in chunks.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is `but not a list of everything inside that container`?